# ruby, wrong number of columns attempting to import csv into in-memory database

Tags: ruby, sqlite, csv, sequel

I have a problem when I'm trying to import data from a file into a database for a test. The following code does exactly as I expect, in the Ruby shell:

```
jruby-1.7.4 :001 > require('sequel')
 => true
jruby-1.7.4 :002 > require('csv')
 => true
jruby-1.7.4 :003 > file = CSV.read('./spec/test_data/registration_sessions.csv')
 => [["01", "EG000000001"], ["02", "EG000000002"], ["03", "EG000000002"]]
jruby-1.7.4 :004 > db = Sequel.connect('jdbc:sqlite::memory:')
 => #<Sequel::JDBC::Database: "jdbc:sqlite::memory:">
jruby-1.7.4 :005 > db.create_table(:registration_sessions) do
jruby-1.7.4 :006 >   Integer :id
jruby-1.7.4 :007?>   String :device_serial
jruby-1.7.4 :008?> end
 => nil
jruby-1.7.4 :009 > db[:registration_sessions]
 => #<Sequel::JDBC::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM `registration_sessions`">
jruby-1.7.4 :010 > db[:registration_sessions].import(db[:registration_sessions].columns, file)
 => ["INSERT INTO `registration_sessions` (`id`, `device_serial`) VALUES ('01', 'EG000000001')", "INSERT INTO `registration_sessions` (`id`, `device_serial`) VALUES ('02', 'EG000000002')", "INSERT INTO `registration_sessions` (`id`, `device_serial`) VALUES ('03', 'EG000000002')"]
jruby-1.7.4 :012 > db[:registration_sessions].all
 => [{:id=>1, :device_serial=>"EG000000001"}, {:id=>2, :device_serial=>"EG000000002"}, {:id=>3, :device_serial=>"EG000000002"}]
```

But in my test, things don't go as expected:

```
let(:registration_metrics_db) { create_registration_metrics_db }
let(:session_seed_data) { CSV.read('./spec/test_data/registration_sessions.csv') }

before(:each) do
    seed_test_data(registration_metrics_db[:registration_sessions], session_seed_data)
end

def create_registration_metrics_db
  db = Sequel.connect('jdbc:sqlite::memory:')

  db.create_table(:registration_sessions) do
    Integer :id
    String :device_serial
  end

  db
end

def seed_test_data(table, data)
  table.import(table.columns, data)
end
```

Which leads to the following, when I run my tests:

```
  14) RegistrationMetricsQueries #get_registration_metrics should return only durations for sessions that contain the start and end moment
     Failure/Error: seed_test_data(registration_metrics_db[:registration_sessions], session_seed_data)
     Sequel::Error:
       Different number of values and columns given to insert_sql
     # ./spec/services/tablet_usage_queries_spec.rb:88:in `seed_test_data'
     # ./spec/services/registration_metrics_queries_spec.rb:10:in `(root)'

  15) RegistrationMetricsQueries #get_registration_metrics should return durations in seconds for valid registration sessions, which contain the start and end moment
     Failure/Error: seed_test_data(registration_metrics_db[:registration_sessions], session_seed_data)
     Sequel::Error:
       Different number of values and columns given to insert_sql
     # ./spec/services/tablet_usage_queries_spec.rb:88:in `seed_test_data'
     # ./spec/services/registration_metrics_queries_spec.rb:10:in `(root)'
```

Am I doing it wrong?

edit: oh, and my sample data

```
01,EG000000001
02,EG000000002
03,EG000000002
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue is a result of a failure to insert. There's a table join that happens under the hood and it's causing Sequel to lock up because sqlite doesn't support right joins. I'm migrating my tests to use an actual mysql database, not an in-memory sqlite db.